# android: setTest of another layout (but inflated) not working

Tags: java, android, layout, android-inflate

I try to edit a text of another layout in android.
I already inflted the textview but the text don't move ...

```
View rowLink = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.nav_header_acceuil, null);
TextView nameText = (TextView) rowLink.findViewById(R.id.nameText);
TextView mailText = (TextView) rowLink.findViewById(R.id.mail);
nameText.setText("test");
```

no changes on the text ...

Comment: I couldn't understand what exactly you are doing. This text belongs to same activity right ?

Comment: i found what i search, i will reply to my own post for the comunity later :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i wanted to modify a TextView into a Header layout of a navigationView from the main activity class.

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
View view = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_acceuil);
TextView nameText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameText);
nameText.setText(prefs.getString("be.mariusvnh.classroom.user.name", "") + " " + prefs.getString("be.mariusvnh.classroom.user.lastName", ""));
```

That's it , I changed the username connected in the application in the navigationView !! :D